# why doesnt this bash script get all the files?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cp, stat

I have a large folder with subfolders of pdf files. I want to get all the pdf files (290 of them) and get them into one directory. (I thought that would be simple.) so that I can concatenate them into one document with my pdf program pdfshuffle, or something like that. I got the files path and names into a file: `out.txt`, using:   `find $(pwd) -iname '*.PDF' > out.txt`
out.txt contains paths and files like this:

```
...
/home/user/Downloads/pedals/PEDALS/Electro-Harmonix/Small Stone Phaser.PDF
/home/user/Downloads/pedals/PEDALS/Electro-Harmonix/Dr. Quack (Doctor Q Melhorado).pdf
/home/user/Downloads/pedals/PEDALS/Marshall/Guv'Nor 1.PDF
/home/user/Downloads/pedals/PEDALS/Marshall/Guv'Nor 2.pdf
...
```

cool. so then I thought I could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="out.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  #echo "$line"
cp $line .
done < "$input"
```

But it only coppies about 36 of the pdfs, and the shell says it cannot stat files:

```
...
cp: cannot stat 'Boogie/Vtwin.pdf': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/home/user/Downloads/pedals/PEDALS/Mesa': No such file or directory
...
```

The file is clearly there, and I can view it etc. whats the problem with my method or script?

Comment: is it becuase the filenames have spaces in them? Im looking at the files that were copied, and it seems none of them have spaces in the filenames.

Comment: Yes, the unquoted `$line` will be subject to word splitting on the default (whitespace) IFS - the `IFS=` assignment only unsets IFS for the `read` command itself

Comment: cool, that was it. i did `cp "$line" .` and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling filenames containing spaces or other funny characters is easily done, using `find` and `xargs`. Read `man find xargs` and do something like

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r echo mv -t $PWD
```

to verify commands, and when they correspond to expectations...
remove the "`echo`" to actually execute the commands.